# Can to_tsvector be used on a column having single word rather than a sentence?

Tags: postgresql-9.4

I am trying to find the English words in a Column "Name" in Postgresql.
I found the function "to_tsvector" does this:
If the name has a column with value "The Best Dogs", the vector returns the following tokens:
best:2 dogs:3

I wonder if it will work when the input is a single word (rather than a sentence)
For e.g. value "Dogs" in the column
Can I expect Dogs:1

I tried and its not working, I am wondering if its a configuration issue or the input format issue.

Comment: Works for me: http://rextester.com/RIKUM68890

Comment: Great, thanks!. I am using it on a column of type 'Text'. Non-English words are brought in as tokens too. Any way to get rid of them?